# Long version of block passed to map returns Enumerator?

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerator

Why does the long version of passing a block to Array#map (#2 below) return an enumerator, while #1 and #3 below return arrays?

Method #1: Returns an array

```
result = [1, 2, 3].map do |num|
  num * 2
end
p result
```

Method #2: Returns an enumerator

```
p [1, 2, 3].map do |num|
  num * 2
end
```

Method #3: Returns an array

```
p [1, 2, 3].map {|num| num * 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

In #2, you are passing the return value of `map`, which is an enumerator, into `p`.

`[1, 2, 3].map #returns an enumerator`

In #1 and #3, on the other hand, you are passing the block directly into `map`, so the return value is an array.

```
p ([1, 2, 3].map do |num|
  num * 2
end) # returns an array
```

If you enclose the whole thing in brackets, it will give you the proper return value.